# ReSharper custom pattern expression variables of type, but not of literal type

Tags: resharper

I'm developing some custom patterns in ReSharper to make things a bit easier, and I've run into a bit of a snag.

One of my patterns is that I want to replace any instance of string.Compare when used for testing equality, and replace it with string.Equals.  This is easy enough at first blush.

I created a pattern:

```
string.Compare($STRING1$, $STRING2$, $STRINGCOMPAREOPTIONS$) == 0
```

Here, $STRINGCOMPAREOPTIONS$ is an expression of type StringComparison.  This words great for this case:

```
if(string.Compare("Foo", "Bar", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0)
```

And of course my replace pattern is simple as well:

```
 string.Equals($STRING1$, $STRING2$, $STRINGCOMPAREOPTIONS$)
```

Now, I need to do the case of using the non-culture version.  This one looks like this:

```
if (string.Compare("Foo", "Bar", true) == 0)
```

Now, here, ReSharper already has a built-in inspector to convert this to using the StringComparison operator, but the problem is that I then have to do a second conversion to use the Equals.. i'd rather write one that does the conversion in one step.

I can obviously write separate true and false versions like so:

```
string.Compare($STRING1$, $STRING2$, true) == 0
```

and

```
string.Equals($STRING1$, $STRING2$, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

But, that doesn't take into account the case where someone writes something like this:

```
string.Compare($STRING1$, $STRING2$, someVariable) == 0
```

So, what I need is an expression that is of type bool, but is not the literal true or false so that I can create a version that adds a conditional.

Any ideas on how I might be able to create a pattern that is of a type, but not of the literal type?